# How to make Keycloak use its database password from keyvault instead of env file

Tags: jboss, keycloak

Currently I am using **keycloak** on **postgres** db. and the db `creds` are provided to environment files. Wanted to know how I can make keycloak obtain the db `creds` from **keyvault** something like **Azure keyvault** ? Is there any documentation / guideline around it?

Comment: I am using the jboss/keycloak docker container and would like the container use database password fetched from a keyvault /  and not through env file....

Answer (score 2):

As per the official documentation ,some part already done but look like still work in progress

> To use a vault, a vault provider must be registered within Keycloak.
>   It is possible to either use a built-in provider described below or
>   implement your own provider. See the Server Developer Guide for more
>   information.

To obtain a secret from a vault instead of entering it directly, enter the following specially crafted string into the appropriate field: `${vault.entry-name}` where you replace the entry-name with the name of the secret as recognized by the vault.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_vault-administration

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-3205

Comment: The documentation says supported fields are  1. Realm private keys (via key provider)
Client secret
Identity brokering credentials
LDAP credentials
SMTP credentials. Any idea if db password is supported and how?

Comment: @UdayaBhaskarReddy Please check the issue link,as per link its look like under progress .